# Include subdomain for constrained route in Rails url helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

Say I have the following routes that are constrained to specific subdomains:

```
App::Application.routes.draw do
  constraints :subdomain => "admin" do
    scope :module => "backend", :as => "backend" do
      resources :signups
      root :to => "signups#index"
    end
  end
  constraints :subdomain => "www" do
    resources :main
    root :to => "main#landing"
  end
end
```

My problem is that `root_url` and `backend_root_url` both returns a url on the current subdomain: "http://**current-subdomain**.lvh.me/" instead the subdomain specific for the resource.
I would like `root_url` to return "http://**www**.lvh.me/" and `backend_root_url` to return "http://**admin**.lvh.me/" (the behavior should be the same for all resources under the subdomain).

I have tried to accomplish this in rails 3.2 by setting the url options in various places, one being url_options in application controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def url_options
    {host: "lvh.me", only_path: false}.merge(super)
  end
end
```

Maybe I need to override the url helpers manually? How would I approach that (accessing the routes etc)?

Edit: I'm able to get the correct result using root_url(:subdomain => "admin") which returns "http://**admin**.lvh.me/" regardless of the current subdomain. However, I would prefer not having to specify this all over the code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using "defaults" as shown below will make rails url helpers output the correct subdomain.

```
App::Application.routes.draw do
  constraints :subdomain => "admin" do
    scope :module => "backend", :as => "backend" do
      defaults :subdomain => "admin" do
        resources :signups
        root :to => "signups#index", :subdomain => "admin"
      end
    end
  end

  constraints :subdomain => "www" do
    defaults :subdomain => "www" do
      resources :main
      root :to => "main#landing"
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: This works great!  One issue I ran into is that this only works if your base domain doesn't already include a subdomain.  If it does, you need to include that as :host.  Or you can set :host by defining ApplicationController#default_url_options to return a hash containing :host.

Comment: I take it back, even that doesn't solve the problem if you already have a subdomain for your main host name.  I haven't figured out a way to do it without writing your own helper method.